# What is the way to get updated position in a list after dropping elements?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a function `cyclePart` which has a definition for the case

```
cyclePart[list_->{},n_,Δn_,cycle_:True]:=...
```

But for example in the algorithm, if it encounters a case like

```
cyclePart[{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}->{b,d,i,j},5,2,True]
```

I want it to transform it into the previous form so its base definition can be applied. In this case, the number `5` is referring to the position in the original list and the list to the right of the arrow tells it to drop these elements.

```
cyclePart[list_->drop_,n_,Δn_,cycle_:True]:=
    cyclePart[Complement[list,drop]->{},...updated n...,Δn,cycle]
```

But how to transform `n` here? Is there a builtin function that can get an updated position after element drops? Note in the example, the updated list's position `3` refers to position `5` since two elements `{b,d}` to the left of position `5` are being removed so position `5` moves down to position `3`.

---

As seen in the comment of @kglr `Complement[list, drop]` should be changed to `DeleteCases[list, Alternatives @@ drop]` since the former is a set drop which means it removes duplicates and sorts the list in addition to the drop. I incorrectly used `Complement[list, drop]` but meant the actions of `DeleteCases[list, Alternatives @@ drop]`.

Comment: `cyclePart[list_ -> drop_, n_, \[CapitalDelta]n_, cycle_: True] := 
 Module[{newlist = DeleteCases[list, Alternatives @@ drop]}, 
  cyclePart[newlist -> {}, 
   Position[newlist, list[[n]]], \[CapitalDelta]n, cycle]]`?

Comment: ...or `cyclePart[list_ -> drop_, n_, \[CapitalDelta]n_, cycle_: True] := 
 Module[{newlist = DeleteCases[list, Alternatives @@ drop]}, 
  cyclePart[newlist -> {}, 
   PositionIndex[newlist][list[[n]]], \[CapitalDelta]n, cycle]]`?

Comment: @kglr incorrect behaviour for `cyclePart[{e,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,e}->{b,d,i,j},5,2,True]`

Comment: Is there a way to look at the positions directly rather than looking at positions through the values of elements. Which is causing extra matching to occur.

Comment: One dirty trick might be to do a `ReplacePart` on the original list to differentiate the element first then use this trick but that doesn't seem like a professional way of doing it. Is there a function that can target positions directly?

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html).

With the partial definition for `cyclePart`.

```
ClearAll[cyclePart]
cyclePart[list_ -> {}, n_, Δn_, cycle_ : True] := {list, {}, n, Δn, cycle}

cyclePart[list_ -> drop_, n_, Δn_, cycle_ : True] :=
 With[{c = Complement[list, drop]},
  cyclePart[
   c -> {},
   Position[c, list[[n]]][[1, 1]],
   Δn, 
   cycle
  ]
 ]
```

Then

```
cyclePart[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j} -> {b, d, i, j}, 5, 2, True]
```

> ```
> {{a, c, e, f, g, h}, {}, 3, 2, True}
> ```

```
cyclePart[{e, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, e} -> {b, d, i, j}, 5, 2, True]
```

> ```
> {{c, e, f, g, h}, {}, 2, 2, True}
> ```

```
cyclePart[{e, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, e} -> {b, d, i, j}, 8, 2, True]
```

> ```
> {{c, e, f, g, h}, {}, 5, 2, True}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[cyclePart]
cyclePart[list_ -> {}, n_, Δn_, cycle_: True] := foo[list -> {}, n, Δn, cycle]

cyclePart[list_ -> drop_, n_, Δn_, cycle_: True] := Module[{newlist = 
     DeleteCases[list, Alternatives @@ drop]}, 
  cyclePart[newlist -> {}, n - Count[list[[;; n]], Alternatives @@ drop], Δn, cycle]]
```

***Examples:***

```
cyclePart[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j} -> {b, d, i, j}, 5, 2, True]
```

> foo[{a, c, e, f, g, h} -> {}, 3, 2, True]

```
cyclePart[{e, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, e} -> {b, d, i, j}, 5, 2, True]
```

> foo[{e, c, e, f, g, h, e} -> {}, 3, 2, True]

```
cyclePart[{e, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, e} -> {b, d, i, j}, 6, 2, True]
```

> foo[{e, c, e, f, g, h, e} -> {}, 4, 2, True]